# Which performs better, pre sorting data or Angular orderBy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

If I have a set of data which is given to me which may not be sorted, would it be better to sort this data myself within my controller or just allow angular to handle the sorting in my ng-repeat  filter using orderBy?

Things I know:

1. Once I load the data from the API, the data will not change. That is, new items will not be added to the set, items will not be removed from the set, and the name field which I am interested in sorting alphabetically by will never change. Therefore I only need to ever sort this data ONCE per page load.
2. The view displaying the data will never need to change the order. That is, there is no way to change the direction of the sort or sort by a different column.

In other words, once sorted, my the data order will remain static. I am currently using orderBy but I am wondering if angular is wasting processing watching the elements order for no reason. Would it maybe be safer to just sort once within my control before handing to the ng-repeat? If I do it this way, will the items definitely remain in this order, even if I user a name filter or use ng-show/hide/if to temporarily hide some elements?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you to do pre sort and put the data in the cache. Then it will  taken from the cache, which is much faster, than collecting data from API each single time.

Comment: sorting in controller is always faster. The only problem is that if you have a lot of different things, it can be quite tricky to update all them properly.

Comment: Great, thanks everyone for confirming my suspicion that orderBy was needless overhead in my case. I will look into other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend sorting in the controller before loading on the screen as your data is not dynamic. On every digest cycle your `ng-repeat` directive is going to rerender the data on the screen and adding an  `orderBy` filter here would certainly be an overhead, I would also recommend caching the data if you know that this data is never bound to change.

Comment: In addition to this, something that might help would be to look into the native bindonce, especially if the data is static.

Answer (score 1):

Sort in a factory/service if you have lots of data then just inject the factory in your controller.